# How to set ymin and ymax in a timechart render?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-oms

How can I set `ymin` and `ymax` in a `timechart` render?

```
let resourceGroupName = "my-resource-group-name";
let hosts = Heartbeat | where ResourceGroup == resourceGroupName | summarize by Computer;
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and Computer in (hosts)
| summarize CPU = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Computer
| render timechart with (ymin=0, ymax=100)
```

I read the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/renderoperator) and I tried to set it like this, but didn't work:

```
| render timechart with (ymin=0, ymax=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The docs you're referring to relate to a different client/service than the one you're using. Azure Data Explorer ("Kusto") is the one the docs are referring to, and as they call out:

> The render operator has no impact on the results returned for the query, other than to inject a annotation (called "Visualization") that contains the rendering information provided in the query. **User agents might not render results as instructed, depending on their support for the required rendering instructions.**

As an example, at least two clients (which can only be used for querying Azure Data Explorer clusters at the moment) - [Kusto.Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) and the [Azure Data Explorer web UX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data) - do take the rendering information into account when rendering charts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yoni. I see, but I'm pinning query result charts in my Dashboard. One of then it's CPU % and I want to set the ymin and ymax. In the dashboard there's no options to set ymin and ymax for queries graphs. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: my reply was to explain why the docs you were referring to were not relevant to the solution you're currently using. unfortunately, i have very limited knowledge about that service or its dashboarding/charting capabilities. others reading this post may know more